# Scaling image on both axis

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to resize an image with different scaling factors on each axis. I am trying to scale the rows (x axis) by 0.60 and the columns (y axis) by 0.80. I have tried a for loop in the command line, but it didn't help much

```
rowValues = size(myImage, 1);
for row = 1: rowValues
    myImage(row) = imresize(myImage(row), 0.60));
end

colValues = size(myImage, 2);
for col = 1: colValues
    myImage(col) = imresize(myImage(col), 0.80));
end
```

but the code doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Does this even work without erroring out? Why not use the `B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols])` syntax?

Comment: I thought about that, but the [numRows, numCols] multiplier was throwing me off.

Comment: What does "throwing me off" mean?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Something like resized = imresize(myImage, [x * 0.60, y * 0.80]);